# PHP upload an image to a folder

Tags: php, image, forms, upload, updating

i am using a form to upload images with the name of thier product ID and it works perfectly on my localhost but when i try to add or update a product throu my hosted site the image upload does't get uploaded, the code working on localhost is :

```
if(isset($_POST['variete']) === true)
{  
    $newname  =  $id.".jpg";
    $location = '/img/products_img/';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$location.$newname);
}
```

Comment: Check directory permissions, check log-file for warnings.

Comment: you're not doing any checking whatsoever to see if move_uploaded_file worked or not.  Chances are it's a permissions issue and/or you need to make sure the directory exists first.

Comment: how can i fix the permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can add following code to the top of your script in orderd to see errors

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

also make sure, you set the enctype of form to 'multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to permission problem

set permission as 0755 to folder '/img/products_img/'

run the following command in server

`chmod 755 /img/products_img/`